# Perl: Transfer substring positions between two strings

Tags: string, algorithm, perl, substring

I'm writing a Perl programm and I've got the following problem:
I have a large list of start and end positions in a string. This positions correspond to substrings in this string. I now want to transfer this positions to a second string. This second string is identical to the first string, except that it has additional hyphen.

Example for original String: "ABCDEF" and one Substring "BCDE"

What I have:

- Positions of substring in this original string: Start = 1, End =
  4
- The original string with additional hyphen: "-AB---CD--E-F---"

What I want:

- Position of the substring in the hyphen-string: Start=2, End=10

I have a large list of this substring positions.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, perhaps we can help with that. If you need to learn Perl, try the [Modern Perl Book](http://www.onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/index.html).

Comment: Yes, [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Do the substring characters have to appear in the same order, i.e. "-AC-BD-E-F" would not match?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect that you have shown a reduced version of the problem, in which case any solution may not work for the real situation.

However, it seems simplest to build a regex by interspersing `-*` (i.e. zero or more hyphens) between characters.

This program works that way, building a regex of `B-*C-*D-*E` and comparing it to both of your sample strings.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @strings = qw/ ABCDEF -AB---CD--E-F--- /;
my ($start, $end) = (1, 4);
my $substr = substr $strings[0], $start, $end-$start + 1;

my $regex = join '-*', split //, $substr;
$regex = qr/$regex/;

for my $string (@strings) {
  if ($string =~ $regex) {
    printf "Substring found at %d to %d in string %s\n", $-[0], $+[0]-1, $string;
  }
}
```

**output**

```
Substring found at 1 to 4 in string ABCDEF
Substring found at 2 to 10 in string -AB---CD--E-F---
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $theStringGivenAsAnInputExample="-AB---CD--E-F---";
my $start=1;
my $end=4;
my $theStringGivenAsAnotherInput="ABCDEF";
my $regexp=join("-*",split("",substr($theStringGivenAsAnotherInput,$start,$end))
);
$theStringGivenAsAnInputExample =~ /$regexp/p;

print ${^PREMATCH},"\n";
print ${^POSTMATCH},"\n";
print ${^MATCH},"\n";

my $startPosition = length(${^PREMATCH});
my $finishPosition = length(${^PREMATCH})+length(${^MATCH})-1;

print "start, $startPosition finish, $finishPosition\n";
```

Comment: *Always* `use strict` and `use warnings`, and please use sensible variable names.

Comment: @Borodin altered for your pleasure

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? It just searches for the characters specified by start and end in the hyphenated string and returns their indices.

```
sub hyphen_substrings {
    my $original   = shift;
    my $hyphenated = shift;
    my @substrings = @_;
    my @return;
    for my $substring (@substrings) {
        my ($start, $end) = @{$substring}[0, 1];
        my $start_h       = index $hyphenated, substr $original, $start, 1;
        my $end_h         = index $hyphenated, substr $original, $end, 1;
        push @return, [$start_h, $end_h];
    }
    return @return;
}
```